# Python - failed using pexpect/pxssh

Tags: python

i'm pretty new with python and i'm trying to make a simple ssh session and run a simple command.
i know that i can use "paramiko" but i decide to use pexpect/pxssh and i installed the last version.

my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pexpect import *
import pexpect
import pxssh
import getpass
import time
import os

try:
    s = pexpect.pxssh()
    hostname = raw_input('hostname:')
    username = raw_input('usernmae:')
    s.login((hostnmae,username,password)
    s.sendline ('uptime')
    s.prompt()
    print s.before
    s.sendline ('ls -l')
    s.prompt()
    print s.before
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
    print "pxssh failed"
    print str(e)
```

but it fails with the following:

```
$ python pssh.py
  File "pssh.py", line 15
    s.sendline ('uptime')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

can someone please help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Watch out for extra "(" in `s.login((hostnmae,username,password)`

Comment: Thanks man (:  but it take some seconds until i get the answer even that both servers are in the same network. is there any way to speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various problems in your code:

1. It should be

   ```
   s = pexpect.pxssh.pxssh()
   ```
2. Check for extra "(" and variable `hostname` on line.

   ```
   s.login((hostnmae,username,password)
   ```
3. And you need password for the ssh before above line.

   ```
    import getpass()
    password = getpass.getpass()
   ```

Comment: Thanks man (: but it take some seconds until i get the answer even that both servers are in the same network. is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: please accept the answer :).. Speed up your ssh. See if even doing this with bash is slow?

Comment: with bash it's perfect but i want to study python :) why i the command output to the screen and to a variable is not the same?

Comment: May be time for new question on Stackoverflow :)