# How to run remote shell command using python script

Tags: python, shell, command, backup

I tried to run remote command to back up my server db, after dumbing it I can't figure out how to remotely get the datas.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Found some documentation, but that didn't really helped me.

Comment: you want to do ssh and run command?

Comment: How about like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794407/python-failed-using-pexpect-pxssh/28794572#28794572

Answer (score 1):

Most databases have some remote-backup service available, so I'd look into that first.

That said, you could use a library that simplifies secure-shell operations. One of those is [`Fabric`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/index.html) which was based on [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/).

Fabric was designed for things like remote backups (or deployments). You want to look specifically at it's [`get`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.get) operation capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to read this documentation.

=> https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#socket-creation

Best regards,

Greg

Comment: please include necessary snippets of this documentation in your answer